# table row filtering with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

im not so close with js or jquery, but i have a table with some entries. now i'd like to filter this table by a list on the left side.

i wrote an example. http://jsfiddle.net/B2Muh/2/

```
<ul class="filter">
    <li class="filter-header"> Filter argument 1: </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Yahoo </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Google </a></li>
    <li class="filter-header"> Filter argument 2: </li>
    <li><a href="#"> GPH_est </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Q_est </a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tableResult">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Yahoo</td>
            <td>GPH_est</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Google</td>
            <td>Q_est</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

the example is very simple. so what i want is, that i can click on any filter argument 1, set this active, and the table shows all entries with the first argument, then if i click on any filter argument 2, the table only shall show entries with the first and the second argument.

i use python and django.

i hope anyone can help me, because i have no idea :)

EDIT: now i have added the markups

Comment: will you be able to modify the html markup, like adding some class attributes etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocked up the functionaltiy you requested, using some slow, simple, exhaustive checks. --http://jsfiddle.net/B2Muh/3/

```
$(function () {
    $filterArgs = $("ul li").filter(function () {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        return txt.indexOf("Filter") < 0;
    });
    $filterArgs.click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $("table tr").hide();
        $("table tr td").each(function () {
            $rowData = $(this);
            $filterArgs.filter(".active").each(function () {
                if ($rowData.text() == $(this).text()) {
                    $rowData.parent().show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: (this was before your modification, but you should be able to make those changes by following this pattern)

Comment: it works nice, but if i choose one filter argument 1 and one filter argument 2 it shows me all entry with the argument 1 and all entries with the argument 2. i'd like to have it so, that if i choose 2 arguments that only entries with the first argument and the second argument are shown.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a sample code. I think this is what you want.

```
    $('body').on('click','li',function(){

    var filterText=$(this).html().trim();
    var splicedTextArray=filterText.split(" ");
    var filter=splicedTextArray[0].toLowerCase();

    $('tr').each(function(index,value){

        var valueText=$(this).find('td:first').html();
        var isRegexmatch=valueText.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter);

        if(isRegexmatch<0)
        {
        $(this).hide();
        }else
        {
        $(this).show();
        }


    });

});
```

**[See it in action on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B2Muh/4/)**

Comment: Sorry I've misplaced the link.. Now you can see it.

Comment: sry but doesn't work if i choose argument 1 and then argument 2.

Comment: You can tweak up the code to make it possible. It was just a mock up for demonstration.

Comment: I am not getting error in jsfiddle link above. If you have changed the code then please provide the link so that i can check.

Comment: thx for your solution, but the other fits more for my problem :)